# In_array function is not working in php

Tags: php

I have 2 arrays, first is `$brand2`, which has repeated values `Selafone`. I want to insert array `$brand2` to `$finalarray` without the repeated value, a value present only once. But I got the $finalarray with repeated values.. Anybody give any suggestion? My code is given below.

```
$finalarray=array(); 
$brand='Selafone -Selafone2-Selafone';
$brand2=explode('-', $brand);

for ($i=0; $i<count($brand2); $i++)
{
    if (in_array($brand2[$i], $finalarray))  
    {
        echo "kkkkkk";
    }
    else
    {
        array_push($finalarray, $brand2[$i]);
    }
}

print_r($finalarray);
```

Print out put $finalarray is

```
Array ( [0] => Selafone [1] => Selafone2 [2] => Selafone )
```

Comment: `array_unique` + your first element has extra space in the end. So it's not equal to the 3rd. Be careful with your data.

Comment: use trim while array_push

Comment: Of course it's working as it is supposed to. `Selafone ` is not equal to `Selafone` - note the white space at the end of the first string.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Try this, It is because of whitespace, So Use `trim($brand2[$i])`. To remove the whitespace.

**Current Solution:**

```
<?php
      $finalarray=array(); 
     $brand='Selafone -Selafone2-Selafone';
     $brand2=explode('-',$brand);

      for($i=0;$i<count($brand2);$i++)
       {

         if(in_array(trim($brand2[$i]),$finalarray))  
          {
          echo "kkkkkk";

          }
         else
         {
          array_push($finalarray,trim($brand2[$i]));

         }
       }
   print_r($finalarray);

  ?>
```

**OUTPUT:**

kkkkkkArray ( [0] => Selafone [1] => Selafone2 )

**Optimized Solution:**

```
  $brand = 'Selafone -Selafone2-Selafone';
  $brand2 = explode('-',$brand);
  $finalarray = array_unique(array_map('trim', $brand2));
  print_r($finalarray);
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like it's working pretty good to me. Look better at the output (use `var_dump()`) and you'll notice some differences in what looks like identical values. One of the `Selafone` contains a space in the result.

Answer (score 0):

use

```
array_push($finalarray, trim($brand2[$i]));
```

instead

```
array_push($finalarray, $brand2[$i]);
```

Answer (score 0):

Just try this custom code ...

```
    $finalarray=array(); 
    $brand='Selafone -Selafone2-Selafone';
    $brand2=explode('-',$brand);
    $num = count($brand2);
    $new = array();
    for($i=0; $i<$num ; $i++){
        $data = $brand2[$i]."<br/>";
        foreach($brand2 as $value){
            if($value !== $brand2[$i]){
                $new = $value; 
            }
        }
    }
    print_r($new);
```

?>
Give it a try